# Solve $\sin 7x+\sin 3x=0$

Tags: trigonometry

I tried it by graph plotting, but it is going so ugly. On solving it on paper it mixed up. Is there any other process to solve?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What did you do on paper?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: 
by addition formulas you have
$$\sin (5x+2x) = \sin 5x \cos 2x + \cos 5x \sin 2x$$
$$\sin (5x-2x) = \sin 5x \cos 2x - \cos 5x \sin 2x$$
so if you add the two equations you end up with
$$\sin (5x+2x) + \sin (5x-2x) = 2\sin 5x \cos 2x.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Use [Prosthaphaeresis Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html)

and $\sin y=0\implies y=m\pi$

and $\cos z=0\implies z=(2r+1)\dfrac\pi2$

---

---

OR

$$\sin7x-\sin3x=\sin(-3x)\implies7x=n\pi+(-1)^n(-3x)$$ where $m,n,r$ are arbitrary integers

Can you show equivalence of the two results?